# Understanding where an amazon ec2 instance run?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am currently using the aws api from my local desktop. I can successfully take backups of my amazon volumes, and even create an ami from it. Now when i wanted to run the instance to be built from this ami, where does the instance run? In their Elastic Cloud or the computer from which the command was issued.

---

Suppose I want to create the new instance in a new region? (locations as defined in ec2-describe-regions) How would I do that? It seems i have a bad knowledge about how the relation between amazon volumes and instances? Please explain it. I am only allowed to use the CLI tools to do all of my work.

---

I made a new snapshot of the existing instance, made an ami using ec2-register, made a keypair, and then followed these steps, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-an-instance.html#launching-an-instance-cli but i got an error as this

```
Client.InvalidParameterValue: The requested instance type's architecture (i386) does not match the architecture in the manifest for aki-fc37bacc (x86_64)
```

my local computer is 32bit. But I do not want to load instance on the local computer but on amazon servers?

Comment: The kernel ID has to be the same as when you generated the AMi. You'd be creating the instance on the server. Before doing anything else I'd use the management console (web-based) before messing with the CLI.

Answer (score 3):

> Now when i wanted to run the instance to be built from this ami, where
>   does the instance run?

It runs in whatever region you started it in. If you didn't specify a region, it will run in `us-east-1`.

> Suppose I want to create the new instance in a new region? (locations
>   as defined in ec2-describe-regions) How would I do that?

You use the `--region` option to the command line tools, and specify whatever region you want. Before you do this, you'll need to copy your AMI to the new region, as any specific AMI ID is only accessible from a single region.

> It seems i have a bad knowledge about how the relation between amazon
>   volumes and instances?

Instances and volumes are created within a specific availability zone within a region. Volumes can be associated with a single instance at a time.

> Client.InvalidParameterValue: The requested instance type's
>   architecture (i386) does not match the architecture in the manifest
>   for aki-fc37bacc (x86_64)

You specified that the AMI should be a 64-bit machine, but you're trying to run it with a 32-bit kernel. That's not going to work. Specify a 64-bit AKI and you should be good to go.

> my local computer is 32bit. But I do not
>   want to load instance on the local computer but on amazon servers?

It **is** running on Amazon's servers. How would they manage to start up a VPS on your hardware?